# Can't get a simple jquery slider to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a jquery slider to work on my site.
I have not programmed it because I cannot, I'm just trying to use something that is there and works on the demo site. I have tried several ready to use jquery slideshow and sliders, without any success. I have now found the simplest one available, I think but cannot make this one work either although I think I have followed all the steps instructed..
The one I have now is from "http://responsiveslides.com/", all the files are on Github though:
https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js

I have put this in my html `<head>`

```
<!-- Slideshow begin -->    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,   
            speed: 500,   
            timeout: 4000 
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this in my html

```
<div class="welcome section"><!-- welcome section begin -->
    <img src="mobile/media/logo2s.jpg" alt="" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
            <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0001.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0002.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0003.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- welcome section end -->
```

The `responsiveslides.min.js` is on the server under directory `js`, which is in the same directory as my html. I have also added relevant CSS to my `.css` file, however the slider does not slide.

No transitions at all.
I don't think I have missed anything but obviously I have. Can anyone help?

Comment: Part of my message disapeared, anyways, the above code is the "head" tag and the following in the body tag of my html:<

    <!-- welcome section  -->
    <div class="welcome section">
    <img src="mobile/media/logo2s.jpg" alt="" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
 <div id="wrapper">
 <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
 <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0001.jpg" alt=""></li>
 <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0002.jpg" alt=""></li>
 <li><img src="mobile/media/p_0003.jpg" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
    </div>
 <!-- welcome section  /end    -->

Comment: You definitely didn't follow everything on the page...

Answer (score 0):

Follow everything on the page.

You have this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

You need this (remember to change .jpg file names to 1, 2, etc.):

```
<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

And all the CSS:

```
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Just don't put an id; keep it as it was:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     $(".rslider").responsiveSlides({
         auto: true,   
         speed: 500,   
         timeout: 4000 
     });
   });
```

Hope it works!